# How to display color attribute thumbnail on woocommerce product archive loop?

Tags: woocommerce

I found this code and is displaying the name of the attribute, anyone can help me modify the code so it displays the thumbnail,

Thank you!

```
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'wh_insertAfterShopProductTitle', 12);

function wh_insertAfterShopProductTitle()
{
    global $product;
    $abv = $product->get_attribute('culoare');
    if (empty($abv))
        return;
    echo __($abv);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query everything about your products. It's best to have a look here: [WooCommerce get product details](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-product-info-title-sku-desc-product-object/)

```
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'wh_insertAfterShopProductTitle', 12);

function wh_insertAfterShopProductTitle()
{
    global $product;
    $image = $product->get_image();
   
    echo __($image);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I`m able to get the product image, I want the attribute image. I`ve tried like this but it does not work. 

``` {
    global $product;
    $abv = $product->get_attribute('pa_culoare');
    if (empty($abv))
        return;
 echo ('<p style="font-size: 0.7em"><b>Culori disponibile:</b> '.$abv.'');
 foreach ($abv as $value) {
  echo ('<img style="width:20px;" src="/uploads/2022/02/'.$value.'.jpg">');
 }
 echo ('</p>');
}

```